SELECT @@secure_file_priv; NULL how to fix pls LINUX MAC ONLY

I cannot upload data sources online because it is NULL how do i fix this pls
it should have a local file path. Please help I spent hours trying to figure this out just to upload a data source online to sql :<

Please no pictures of text in questions, only text when the image contains only text

Why is this tagged terminal?

secure_file_priv is a variable which

is not dynamic (cannot be altered in runtime)
has only global scope (cannot be set in/for separate session)

The only way to alter its value is either to edit my.ini file (or any other option file which is loaded during server start) or to specify this option in the server starting command line. With server restarting, of course.

Hello, I am new to working with sql and terminal. Do you mind pls specifying a step-by-step instruction on how to do this?

@mikhaela What "step-by-step instruction"? It's elementary.. Stop server, edit my.ini or service starting command line / script, save, start server.
